# Mexico visa with Indian passport query

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, mexico, visa-free-entry, uk-residents

Hiya we are travelling to Mexico and I have a British passport and my husband has a Indian passport he has a UK spouse visa with leave to remain. Am I right I’m saying he will not need a visa. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For Indian citizens travelling to Mexico, Timatic, the system used by airlines to check required documentation states:

“The following are exempt from holding a visa:

Passengers with a permanent residence permit issued by United Kingdom for a maximum stay of 180 days.”

Source: https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b

This means that your husband must have Indefinite Leave to Remain in order to qualify for visa-free entry.  If he has Limited Leave to Remain, he needs a visa.

Comment: However when I click this link and put details in it says the documents we have are sufficient. I.e the residence permit with leave to remain. I’m very confused

Comment: @Amarjit are you confused by the "for a maximum stay of 180 days" part of the statement? That's the maximum amount of time your husband can stay in Mexico.

Comment: @mkennedy that is also the maximum amount of time the UK passport holder can visit Mexico. Any longer than that requires Mexico residency

Comment: Does OP's husband have indefinite leave to remain / permanent residence though? It seems he has a visa, which is quite temporary.

Comment: @Traveller I know. But OP's husband has a visa it seems, which is neither.

Comment: Looking at gov.uk website regarding spouse visas: "You’ll get permission to stay for 2.5 years, or for 6 months if you’re applying as a fiancé, fiancée or proposed civil partner." That doesn't say permanent anywhere. 

Comment: @kiradotee The terminology used by the OP in their question indicates that the husband does not have ILR. The answer is correct, but I’ll amend it to clarify.

Comment: I guess maybe my comment was more relevant to @Midavalo as they mentioned "In other words your documents are sufficient", which I believe is false. But your answer is obviously correct as it states the facts as they are about the requirements.

Comment: @kiradotee you are correct, I overlooked that. I'll remove my comment